# Enable a short code in the custom meta field

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, metabox

I was wondering if there is a filter that allows me to enable short codes to work inside the custom meta fields in my posts.

I know the following code enables it in widgets:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

And where would I have to put a code? My theme has shortcodes.php also meta-boxes.php

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the content of the custom field through the `do_shortcode()` function when you output. e.g. given a custom field name of 'custom field'

```
echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom-field', true) );
```

Comment: Thanks @nothingtosee, but there would I have to add this code? Functions.php or somewhere else?

Comment: Anywhere you intend to output (i.e. in the theme templates)

Comment: sorry I just want to make sure my code is right before I put it in:  <?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price Check:', true) ); ?>

Comment: As long as your custom field key is 'Price Check:' then yep.

Comment: thanks, but I still can't get it work